# How to Rectify While Loop for Tic-Tac-Toe Game on Python?

Tags: python, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

```
def display_board(board):
    print(board[7]+"|"+board[8]+"|"+board[9])
    print("-|-|-")
    print(board[4]+"|"+board[5]+"|"+board[6])
    print("-|-|-")
    print(board[1]+"|"+board[2]+"|"+board[3])
    print("-|-|-")   

testing_board=[" "]*10
display_board(testing_board)

def player_input():
    marker=" "
    while marker !="x" or marker !="o":
        marker= input("player1 choose x,o: ")

        if marker=="o":
            return ("o","x")
        else:
            return ("x","o")
        break

player_input()

import random

def first_move():
    if random.randint(0,1)==1:
        return "player 2"
    else:
        return "player 1"

def handle_turn(board,marker,position):
    position=input("select a position from 1-9: ")
    position=int(position)
    board[position]=marker

handle_turn(testing_board,"x",8)
display_board(testing_board)

def check_win(board, mark):
    return ((board[7]==mark and board[8]==mark and board[9]==mark)or
    (board[4]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[6]==mark)or
    (board[1]==mark and board[2]==mark and board[3]==mark)or
    (board[7]==mark and board[4]==mark and board[1]==mark)or
    (board[8]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[2]==mark)or
    (board[9]==mark and board[6]==mark and board[3]==mark)or
    (board[7]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[3]==mark)or
    (board[9]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[1]==mark))

check_win(testing_board,"x")

def space_free(board,position):
    return board[position]==" "

def fullboardcheck(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if space_free(board, i):
            return False
    return True

def player_choice(board):
    position = 0

    while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_free(board,position):
        return position

#game start
#board,marker,first player to go
while True:
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    player1_marker, player2_marker = player_input()
    turn = first_move()
    print (turn + " will go first")

   #game play 
    play_game = input('Are you ready to play? Enter Yes or No.')

    if play_game == "Yes":
        game_is_on = True
    else:
        game_is_on = False

    while game_is_on:
        #player1 turn
        if turn=="player 1":
            display_board(theBoard)
            position=player_choice(theBoard)
            handle_turn(theBoard,player1_marker,position)

            if check_win(theBoard,player1_marker):
                display_board(theBoard)
                print('Congratulations! You have won the game!')
                game_is_on=False
            else:
                if fullboardcheck(theBoard):
                    display_board(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a draw!')
                else:
                    turn = 'player 2'

        else:
            display_board(theBoard)
            position = player_choice(theBoard)
            handle_turn(theBoard, player2_marker, position)

            if check_win(theBoard, player2_marker):
                display_board(theBoard)
                print('player 2 has won!')
                game_is_on=False

            else:
                if fullboardcheck(theBoard):
                    display_board(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a draw!')
                else:
                    turn = 'player 1'
```

I am trying to build a tic-tac-toe game on Python. Above is the code I have written till now, and I am getting stuck at the below points.

1. Player 1's first move isn't being registered
2. Player 2's first move is declaring him to be the winner straightaway without any further moves from either player.
3. My while loop isn't working to check whether all positions have been filled or not.

I am new to Python, request some guidance on where I am going wrong.

Comment: The function `handle_turn()` receives a copy of `theBoard` and only changes the copy. This means that the instance of `theBoard` inside your big while loop remains unchanged.

Comment: The board is a list and lists are mutable. The function does change the list outside of the function, but the problem was a few typos made, specifically with turn handling

Comment: Also you aren't using the result of the player_input() call.

Answer (score 0):

I added comments into the code everywhere I found an error. There are some extra commented print statements while I tested to see what was not working. Feel free to remove them. You had some typos in your code that were causing your selection statements to evaluate incorrectly, those typos are pointed out below. I've tested this and it seems to be working now.

```
def display_board(board):
    print(board[7]+"|"+board[8]+"|"+board[9])
    print("-|-|-")
    print(board[4]+"|"+board[5]+"|"+board[6])
    print("-|-|-")
    print(board[1]+"|"+board[2]+"|"+board[3])
    print("-|-|-")

testing_board=[" "]*10
display_board(testing_board)

def player_input():
    marker=" "
    while marker !="x" or marker !="o":
        marker= input("player1 choose x,o: ")

        if marker=="o":
            return ("o","x")
        else:
            return ("x","o")

player_input()

import random

def first_move():
    if random.randint(0,1)==0:
        return "player 2"
    else:
        return "player 1"

def handle_turn(board,marker,position):
    #print("Handling turn")
    position=position #error in this line, you were requesting position again even though you passed it as a parameter. Instead of an input just store the value passed from player_choice.
    position=int(position)
    board[position]=marker
    #print(board[position])
#handle_turn(testing_board,"x"," ")
#display_board(testing_board)

def check_win(board, mark):
    return ((board[7]==mark and board[8]==mark and board[9]==mark)or #error in this line, changed commas to and
    (board[4]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[6]==mark)or
    (board[1]==mark and board[2]==mark and board[3]==mark)or
    (board[7]==mark and board[4]==mark and board[1]==mark)or
    (board[8]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[2]==mark)or
    (board[9]==mark and board[6]==mark and board[3]==mark)or
    (board[7]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[3]==mark)or
    (board[9]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[1]==mark))

check_win(testing_board,"x")

def space_free(board,position):
    return board[position]==" "

def fullboardcheck(board):
    for i in range(1,10):
        if space_free(board, i):
            return False
    return True

def player_choice(board):
    position = 0
    #print("player_choice func")
    while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_free(board, position):
        position = int(input('Choose your next position: (1-9) '))

    return position

#game start
#board,marker,first player to go
while True:
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    player1_marker, player2_marker = player_input()
    turn = first_move()
    print (turn + " will go first")

   #game play 
    play_game = input('Are you ready to play? Enter Yes or No.')

    if play_game == "Yes":
        game_is_on = True
    else:
        game_is_on = False

    while game_is_on:
        #print(turn)
        #print("Player 1:" + player1_marker)
        #print("Player 2:" + player2_marker)
        if turn=="player 1": #typo in this line, you needed a space after player and before 1
            #print("yes")
            display_board(theBoard)
            position=player_choice(theBoard)
            handle_turn(theBoard,player1_marker,position)
            #print(check_win(theBoard,player1_marker))
            if check_win(theBoard,player1_marker):
                display_board(theBoard)
                print('Congratulations! You have won the game!')
                game_is_on=False
            else:
                if fullboardcheck(theBoard):
                    display_board(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a draw!')
                else:
                    turn = 'player 2' #typo in this line, player needed to be lowercase

        else:
            display_board(theBoard)
            position = player_choice(theBoard)
            handle_turn(theBoard, player2_marker, position)

            if check_win(theBoard, player2_marker):
                display_board(theBoard)
                print('Player 2 has won!')
                game_is_on=False

            else:
                if fullboardcheck(theBoard):
                    display_board(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a draw!')
                else:
                    turn = 'player 1' #typo in this line, player needed to be lowercase
```

To address OP concerns in the comments:

```
player1 choose x,o: x
player 2 will go first
Are you ready to play? Enter Yes or No.Yes
 | | 
-|-|-
 | | 
-|-|-
 | | 
-|-|-
Choose your next position: (1-9) 1
 | | 
-|-|-
 | | 
-|-|-
o| | 
-|-|-
Choose your next position: (1-9) 1
Choose your next position: (1-9) 1
Choose your next position: (1-9) 1
Choose your next position: (1-9) 2
 | | 
-|-|-
 | | 
-|-|-
o|x| 
-|-|-
Choose your next position: (1-9) 1
Choose your next position: (1-9) 1
Choose your next position: (1-9) 1
Choose your next position: (1-9) 5
 | | 
-|-|-
 |o| 
-|-|-
o|x| 
-|-|-
Choose your next position: (1-9) 3
 | | 
-|-|-
 |o| 
-|-|-
o|x|x
-|-|-
Choose your next position: (1-9) 3
Choose your next position: (1-9) 2
Choose your next position: (1-9) 1
```

Comment: Thanks for going through my code. A lot of the issues got resolved by the solutions you provided. However, I am still facing one final issue and was wondering if you could also share your inputs on it. When one position is already occupied by a player, and the second player tries inputting at the same position, the first player's input gets overwritten, which ideally shouldn't be the case. How should I address this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you copied what I have there? I just tested it again and it is not overwriting it. I edited my post above to show you what happens when I tried to.